# ReflectionException Class App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\MyController does not exist Laravel Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, api, lumen

I totally new to laravel, I am creating sample api using lumen, I followed same steps from link

https://coderexample.com/restful-api-in-lumen-a-laravel-micro-framework/

Now when i am executing my request through postman its showing following error

[image]

So Please suggest me any solution

Comment: There is a problem in your imports !! `use App\Http\Controllers\MyController;`  !!

Comment: show your code please.

Comment: send a post request and add required parameters